# MySQL Workbench; creating intermediate tables and mapping them

Tags: mysql, mapping, mysql-workbench

I have two tables in MySql Workbench; Categories and Products. I created a third table which contains PK's from the first two tables. How do I sort out which product falls under which category. Do I need to create a fourth table? Also, it is obvious that one category has many products. How do I put this data into the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I use it in my company is I have a `Category` table just as you have, a `Brands` table and a `Products` table (this is the basic setup, I have more tables for price history, product history, etc).

The `Products` table is the primary one, containing a foreign key to each of `Categories` and `Brands`.

Table `tbl_category` and `tbl_brand` has the same structure:

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id    | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name  | varchar(100) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Table `tbl_product`:

```
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| category  | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| brand     | int(11)       | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| spec      | varchar(100)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| descript  | varchar(1000) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| unit      | varchar(10)   | YES  |     | PÇ      |                |
| cost      | decimal(16,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| ..................................................................|
|                                                                   |
+-----------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

And I have the following **foreign keys**:

```
  KEY `product_category_fk` (`category`),
  KEY `product_brand_fk` (`brand`),
  CONSTRAINT `product_brand_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`brand`) REFERENCES `tbl_brand` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `product_category_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`category`) REFERENCES `tbl_category` (`id`) ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The reasoning I used is: **any given product has only one category and one brand**, so I can put that information in the product record itself.

---

This is a good example starting point (Taken from [here](http://www.devcity.net/PrintArticle.aspx?ArticleID=186))

[image]